# Can I use SoundCloud with Midori?

Tags: midori

When I visit [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/), I get an error message that my browser isn't compatible with SoundCloud. What should I do to continue using Midori when opening SoundCloud?

[image: Midori-Soundcloud]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try telling Midori to identify itself as Safari (or another supported browser):

1. Open the Menu (the gear icon in the top right)
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Select the "Network" tab and choose "Safari" from the "Identify As" combobox.

[image: Midori Network Preferences]

Here's [more info from the Midori FAQ](http://midori-browser.org/faqs/#why_does_google_mailcalendarmaps_facebook_not_work_or_show_mobile_version).